# Unable to change time in Android emulator: Alarm driver missing

Tags: android-emulator

I am running Android 4.4 (using custom a custom rooted system image) in the android emulator (from the command line). When trying to set the time via Settings > Date & time ("Automatic date & time" and "Automatic time zone" are disabled) i can set the time (the dialog appears and works), but the system clock is not updated.

Logcat says:

```
D/        ( 1206): Setting time of day to sec=1515250620
W/        ( 1206): Unable to open alarm driver: No such file or directory
```

What could cause the alarm driver to be unavailable/missing and how can i fix this?

**Update**: I have verified that /dev/alarm is missing -- is there any way to add the missing driver without having to recompile android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but some compiling is needed for the driver. Just not the whole custom image.

You need to set-up a cross compiler.

Go to your .config file and set the kernel driver you want to compile to

> =m

using the `menuconfig command`

By selecting 'm' for the kernel driver. This means ``module,'' meaning that the system will compile it, but not directly into the kernel, but as a loadable module."

Now you are ready to compile your specific driver using this make command.

```
make <ARCH= Path to arm-eabi- directory >  <path to the .c file of module>
```

Once compiled go grab the created .ko file. Copy it to

> /system/lib/modules/

within your custom rooted system image.

Lastly, from the terminal emulator use the insmod  command to inject it in. So it would look like

```
su

mount -o rw,remount,rw /system

insmod /system/lib/modules/modulefile.ko
```

That should do it if you encounter any errors read them carefully incase the module is interdependent. Check the Dmesg logs for success or errors.

References:

https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/modular-kernels#loadable-kernel-modules

http://linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/Kernel-HOWTO-4.html